# Face-detection in bash: Simply return number of faces found

Tags: opencv

I need to count the number of faces in a picture on the commandline (to be used in a bash script: `do-something-if-picture-passed-contains-faces, else try next picture`).

So far I have the `facedetect` `OpenCV` example working, but this example continuously displays the picture - all I'd need is a number returned (or, simply an errorcode: `0` if no face found, `1` if a face has been found).

Sadly my C++ skills are abysmal, could someone point me in the right direction?

I'd use python or ruby, but the bindings to OpenCV seem to be more then broken in Ubuntu 12.04, none of the examples work right (or at all).

Thank you!

**Edit:** The example I was talking about as installed by OpenCV under Ubuntu

`cat /usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/examples/c/facedetect.cpp`:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis program demonstrates the cascade recognizer. Now you can use Haar or LBP features.\n"
            "This classifier can recognize many ~rigid objects, it's most known use is for faces.\n"
            "Usage:\n"
            "./facedetect [--cascade=<cascade_path> this is the primary trained classifier such as frontal face]\n"
               "   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path this an optional secondary classifier such as eyes]]\n"
               "   [--scale=<image scale greater or equal to 1, try 1.3 for example>\n"
               "   [filename|camera_index]\n\n"
            "see facedetect.cmd for one call:\n"
            "./facedetect --cascade=\"../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml\" --nested-cascade=\"../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml\" --scale=1.3 \n"
            "Hit any key to quit.\n"
            "Using OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION << "\n" << endl;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale);

String cascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String nestedCascadeName = "../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    Mat frame, frameCopy, image;
    const String scaleOpt = "--scale=";
    size_t scaleOptLen = scaleOpt.length();
    const String cascadeOpt = "--cascade=";
    size_t cascadeOptLen = cascadeOpt.length();
    const String nestedCascadeOpt = "--nested-cascade";
    size_t nestedCascadeOptLen = nestedCascadeOpt.length();
    String inputName;

    help();

    CascadeClassifier cascade, nestedCascade;
    double scale = 1;

    for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        cout << "Processing " << i << " " <<  argv[i] << endl;
        if( cascadeOpt.compare( 0, cascadeOptLen, argv[i], cascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            cascadeName.assign( argv[i] + cascadeOptLen );
            cout << "  from which we have cascadeName= " << cascadeName << endl;
        }
        else if( nestedCascadeOpt.compare( 0, nestedCascadeOptLen, argv[i], nestedCascadeOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( argv[i][nestedCascadeOpt.length()] == '=' )
                nestedCascadeName.assign( argv[i] + nestedCascadeOpt.length() + 1 );
            if( !nestedCascade.load( nestedCascadeName ) )
                cerr << "WARNING: Could not load classifier cascade for nested objects" << endl;
        }
        else if( scaleOpt.compare( 0, scaleOptLen, argv[i], scaleOptLen ) == 0 )
        {
            if( !sscanf( argv[i] + scaleOpt.length(), "%lf", &scale ) || scale < 1 )
                scale = 1;
            cout << " from which we read scale = " << scale << endl;
        }
        else if( argv[i][0] == '-' )
        {
            cerr << "WARNING: Unknown option %s" << argv[i] << endl;
        }
        else
            inputName.assign( argv[i] );
    }

    if( !cascade.load( cascadeName ) )
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade" << endl;
        cerr << "Usage: facedetect [--cascade=<cascade_path>]\n"
            "   [--nested-cascade[=nested_cascade_path]]\n"
            "   [--scale[=<image scale>\n"
            "   [filename|camera_index]\n" << endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    if( inputName.empty() || (isdigit(inputName.c_str()[0]) && inputName.c_str()[1] == '\0') )
    {
        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' );
        int c = inputName.empty() ? 0 : inputName.c_str()[0] - '0' ;
        if(!capture) cout << "Capture from CAM " <<  c << " didn't work" << endl;
    }
    else if( inputName.size() )
    {
        image = imread( inputName, 1 );
        if( image.empty() )
        {
            capture = cvCaptureFromAVI( inputName.c_str() );
            if(!capture) cout << "Capture from AVI didn't work" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        image = imread( "lena.jpg", 1 );
        if(image.empty()) cout << "Couldn't read lena.jpg" << endl;
    }

    cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    if( capture )
    {
        cout << "In capture ..." << endl;
        for(;;)
        {
            IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
            frame = iplImg;
            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
            if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
                frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
            else
                flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

            detectAndDraw( frameCopy, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );

            if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
                goto _cleanup_;
        }

        waitKey(0);

_cleanup_:
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "In image read" << endl;
        if( !image.empty() )
        {
            detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );
            waitKey(0);
        }
        else if( !inputName.empty() )
        {
            /* assume it is a text file containing the
            list of the image filenames to be processed - one per line */
            FILE* f = fopen( inputName.c_str(), "rt" );
            if( f )
            {
                char buf[1000+1];
                while( fgets( buf, 1000, f ) )
                {
                    int len = (int)strlen(buf), c;
                    while( len > 0 && isspace(buf[len-1]) )
                        len--;
                    buf[len] = '\0';
                    cout << "file " << buf << endl;
                    image = imread( buf, 1 );
                    if( !image.empty() )
                    {
                        detectAndDraw( image, cascade, nestedCascade, scale );
                        c = waitKey(0);
                        if( c == 27 || c == 'q' || c == 'Q' )
                            break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cerr << "Aw snap, couldn't read image " << buf << endl;
                    }
                }
                fclose(f);
            }
        }
    }

    cvDestroyWindow("result");

    return 0;
}

void detectAndDraw( Mat& img,
                   CascadeClassifier& cascade, CascadeClassifier& nestedCascade,
                   double scale)
{
    int i = 0;
    double t = 0;
    vector<Rect> faces;
    const static Scalar colors[] =  { CV_RGB(0,0,255),
        CV_RGB(0,128,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,255),
        CV_RGB(0,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,128,0),
        CV_RGB(255,255,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,0),
        CV_RGB(255,0,255)} ;
    Mat gray, smallImg( cvRound (img.rows/scale), cvRound(img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1 );

    cvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    resize( gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR );
    equalizeHist( smallImg, smallImg );

    t = (double)cvGetTickCount();
    cascade.detectMultiScale( smallImg, faces,
        1.1, 2, 0
        //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
        //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
        |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
        ,
        Size(30, 30) );
    t = (double)cvGetTickCount() - t;
    printf( "detection time = %g ms\n", t/((double)cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.) );
    for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin(); r != faces.end(); r++, i++ )
    {
        Mat smallImgROI;
        vector<Rect> nestedObjects;
        Point center;
        Scalar color = colors[i%8];
        int radius;
        center.x = cvRound((r->x + r->width*0.5)*scale);
        center.y = cvRound((r->y + r->height*0.5)*scale);
        radius = cvRound((r->width + r->height)*0.25*scale);
        circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        if( nestedCascade.empty() )
            continue;
        smallImgROI = smallImg(*r);
        nestedCascade.detectMultiScale( smallImgROI, nestedObjects,
            1.1, 2, 0
            //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
            //|CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
            |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            ,
            Size(30, 30) );
        for( vector<Rect>::const_iterator nr = nestedObjects.begin(); nr != nestedObjects.end(); nr++ )
        {
            center.x = cvRound((r->x + nr->x + nr->width*0.5)*scale);
            center.y = cvRound((r->y + nr->y + nr->height*0.5)*scale);
            radius = cvRound((nr->width + nr->height)*0.25*scale);
            circle( img, center, radius, color, 3, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
    cv::imshow( "result", img );
}
```

Comment: Could you post your working example please?

Comment: Of course, sorry. Here you go...

Comment: I just so happened to notice that OpenCV has their own answers section, pleare refer [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2702/simply-count-number-of-faces/) for a working example.

Comment: Well done for finding it @Christian. Could you please post it as an answer and accept it?

Comment: In Chrome nothing happens when I click "Answer Your Question" - and this is the only browser that, somehow, reliably binds my Google account to *.stackexchange.com. I have send this to the "makers" twice, but no answer so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the `void detectAndDraw` to `int detectAndDraw`
2. The `int detectAndDraw` will return `faces.end()-faces.begin();`
   and you will get the number of faces in a picture. hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will try this on the weekend right away!